# Magento API - most efficient way to get list of products and their name/url/image_url

Tags: api

I'm trying to making API calls from my other website to my magento store. If possible, I would like to get a list of products (specified by SKU) and their name/url/image_url in just one call.

Currently I find no way of doing it. The product list only gives me product name. I have to make an api call for each product to get their url/image_url. That's so not efficient. Any better way of doing this?

Running Magento 1.9.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, using multiCall:

```
$methods = array();
foreach($skus as $value){
    $methods[] = array('catalog_product.info',array($value,NULL,array('name','url_path'),'sku'));
    $methods[] = array('catalog_product_attribute_media.list',array($value,NULL,'sku'));
}
$result = $client->multiCall($session, $methods);
```

Comment: Hi @Shawn please help me to define $skus I can't understand what I need to put in $skus variable .
I am new in magento

Comment: It's an array of product's sku numbers.